# Compiling Apache 2.2.11 on AIX 6.1, .so files not genereated

Tags: apache-2.2, aix, gcc

I am compiling Apache 2 (2.2.11 yeh, Its old...but its a requirement) on AIX 6.1 with GCC 4.2.0.  I am using the configure options:

```
./configure \
--enable-module=rewrite\
--enable-module=log_referer\
--with-included-apr \
--enable-proxy  \
--enable-ssl=shared \
--with-ssl=/usr  \
--prefix=/PATH/apache \
--enable-so \
--enable-mods-shared="proxy proxy_http proxy_connect headers mod_proxy mod_ssl"
```

The configure, followed by the make/make install processes all run without error of any kind.  However, when I look int he modules directory for the /PATH/modules directory there are no .so files created.

Sadly because of the nature of what I am doing, and the business I am in, I am locked into the software versions as described.

Comment: No ".so" files, but are there other files generated in the modules directory?

Comment: You might have forgotten to add `-Wl,-brtl` to `LDFLAGS`. Note: it is important to compile apr, apr-util and httpd with the same settings/options/flags (including 'layout'). If you have other components (tomcat-native, tomcat-connector, serf, php) then those too.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use a precompiled RPM from [here](ftp://www.oss4aix.org/everything/RPMS/httpd-2.2.11-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm). The maintainer, Michael Perzl, is a well known IBM specialist, and has a well earned rep for porting software to AIX.

Also in the same site, you will find instructions on [how to compile](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Instructions) for 6.1, although the instructions there use the native AIX `xlc` compiler, possibly for better results.

If you choose to go the precompiled RPMs route, keep an eye on dependencies, which in the case of `http`, can be quite a lot. The [FAQ](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=FAQs.FAQs) contains tips on how to download all the dependencies.